What's the difference between withColumn and with_column in Snowflake?
I have seen that there are many DataFrame functions that are the same - the only difference that one is written in camelCase and other in the snake_case. Does there any performance difference between those functions? What is the purpose of it? Why some of them have duplicates and some of them not?
For example:
DataFrame.withColumn and DataFrame.with_column - there are more examples
More details in documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.select_expr
I tested both of the functions and it seems that they are working as intended.

There is no difference. Snowflake often has aliases for function names for convenience. This specific case can be seen in the dataframe.py source code.
